# SQLAlchemy and Snowflake Query ID

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

It's possible to get the Snowflake Query Id when using the snowflake-connector-python, i.e. the sfqid attribute from the cursor object.

Is it possible to get that attribute when using Snowflake's SQLAlchemy Toolkit?  The doc page doesn't mention it - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I found was using the function [LAST_QUERY_ID](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_query_id.html), something like this:

```
results = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM CITIBIKE_TRIPS LIMIT 1").fetchone()
query_id = connection.execute("SELECT LAST_QUERY_ID()").fetchone()
print(query_id)
```

I get back something like:

```
$ python test_sqlalchemy.py 
('019edb4b-0502-8a31-0000-16490cd95072',)
```

Might not be the ideal way.

Comment: Yes, I have used that before in interactive sessions.  I never thought to use it in this case - good idea!  Thanks.

Comment: This is the method I had to use due since I'm using the SQL Alchemy Session object

Answer (score 3):

You can use sqlalchemy's `execute` method and get a reference to the `SnowflakeCursor` like this:

```py
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

snowflake_username = os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME')
snowflake_password = os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD')
snowflake_account = os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT')
snowflake_warehouse = os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE')
snowflake_database = 'simon_db'
snowflake_schema = 'public'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine(
        'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/{db}/{schema}?warehouse={warehouse}'.format(
            user=snowflake_username,
            password=snowflake_password,
            account=snowflake_account,
            db=snowflake_database,
            schema=snowflake_schema,
            warehouse=snowflake_warehouse,
        )
    )

    connection = engine.connect()

    results = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE")
    queryId = results.cursor.sfqid

    print(f"queryId = {queryId}")
    print(f"results: {results.fetchone()}")

    connection.close()
    engine.dispose()
```

This prints out:

```
queryId = 019edbef-0000-114f-0000-0f9500612j23
results: ('n/a', '2021-01-01')
```

Comment: Well, it turns out I wasn't able to use this approach.  I have coded all my Snowflake database access using the SQLAlchemy Session; which doesn't have a cursor.  The method below from @Sergiu works fine though.